# Big-query creating a sub structure from multiple records

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a data structure that is like this

```
Title1,        category3, type, title,  unit, price 
Mars Bar         Loc1      Choc   Mars    250g  2.00 
Big Mars Bar     Loc1      Choc   Mars    500g  3.50 
Hershey          Loc1      Choc   Hersh   250g  2.10 
Big Hersh Bar    Loc1      Choc   Hersh   500g  3.50 
Ghirdaldi        Loc1      Choc   Ghird   100g  1.00 
Ghirdaldi        Loc1      Choc   Ghird   250g  2.46 
Laura Secord     Loc1      Choc   Laura   100g  1.00 
Cadburys Milk    Loc1      Choc   Cadbur  100g  1.25   
Mars Bar         Loc2      Choc   Mars    250g  2.00 
Big Mars Bar     Loc2      Choc   Mars    500g  3.50 
Hershey          Loc2      Choc   Hersh   250g  2.10 
Big Hersh Bar    Loc2      Choc   Hersh   500g  3.50 
Ghirdaldi        Loc2      Choc   Ghird   100g  1.00 
Ghirdaldi        Loc2      Choc   Ghird   250g  2.46 
Laura Secord     Loc2      Choc   Laura   100g  1.00 
Cadburys Milk    Loc2      Choc   Cadbur  100g  1.25
```

We are producing a price list and we want the structure to be that repeated prices are put in a price list.

```
{
  office:
  manufacturer: 
  order_date:  
  Title1:
  category3: 
  priceList: 
    [
      {
        title:
        price:
      },
      {
        title:
        price:
      }
   ]
 }
```

And so we do this

```
(SELECT category3, type,  ARRAY_AGG (
    STRUCT(unit as title, price as price)
  ) AS priceList, 
  count(*) as rowCount 


  FROM `test-project.Bar.Chocolates` 
  GROUP BY category3, title, type 

  ORDER BY category3, title, type) --As priceList
```

This works exactly as expected and returns what we want. But in the data base we have several other fields we want to include while priceList is a field of rows that returns as a struct / repeatable record.

I tried using array( of this and several other things,

```
SELECT office, manufacturer, order_date, Title1, 


    (SELECT category3, type,  ARRAY_AGG (
        STRUCT(unit as title, price as price)


 ) AS priceList, 
  count(*) as rowCount 


  FROM `test-project.Bar.Chocolates` 
  GROUP BY category3, title, type 

      ORDER BY category3, title, type) --As priceList

FROM `test-project.Bar.Chocolates`
```

and it returned the error "Scalar subquery produced more than one element"

Any thoughts of how I put a "grouped by" Aggregate array beside the rest of the data in the structure would be very helpful.

With thanks,

Comment: provide clear example of input data and expected output (based on input data), so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ARRAY()` to create arrays with the results of a query.

Without `ARRAY()`:

```
SELECT  
  (SELECT AS STRUCT * FROM UNNEST((SELECT SPLIT("1,2,3"))) x) x
```

> Scalar subquery produced more than one element

With `ARRAY()`:

```
SELECT ARRAY
  (SELECT AS STRUCT * FROM UNNEST((SELECT SPLIT("1,2,3"))) x) x
```

[image]